# How to make a list of items flashing on each item sequentially automatically with respect to knowing the index of the current item with flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

trying to make a list of items flashing on each item sequentially automatically with respect to knowing the index of the current item with flutter

[Like This Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ja4p.gif)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly. This should do the trick:

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage>{

  int currentIndex = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    timerMethod();
  }

  void timerMethod(){
    Timer(const Duration(seconds: 3), (){
      setState(() {
        currentIndex++;
      });
      if(currentIndex == 4) currentIndex = 0;
      timerMethod();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 4,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: ListTile(
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50)
              ),
              tileColor: currentIndex == index ? Colors.teal : Colors.tealAccent,
              leading: const CircleAvatar(
                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                child: Icon(Icons.person,color: Colors.teal,),
              ),
              title: Text("Item ${index+1}"),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```